How can pass to rmii from mii in ethernet chip?
I use ksz8081mnx mii ethernet chip.I made my ethernet configuration and it is succesful.
I changed my ethernet chip with ksz8081rnb rmii.I organised dts file but my ethernet not working.
sama5d2.dtsi

macb0: ethernet@f8008000{
compatible = "micrel,sama5d2-gem";
reg=<0xf8008000 0x1000>;
clocks = <&macb0_clk>, <&macb0_clk>;
clock-names = "hclk","pclk";
}

sama5d27_myboard.dtsi
#include sama5d2.dtsi

macb0: ethernet@f8008000 {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_macb0_default &pinctrl_macb0_rst>;
                phy-mode = "rmii";
                status = "okay";
                
                ethernet-phy@0 {
                    reg = <0x0>;
                    interrupt-parent = <&pioA>;
                    interrupts = <PIN_PB2 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
                    pinctrl-names = "default";
                    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_macb0_phy_irq>;
                };

            };

        

pinctrl_macb0_default: macb0_default {
                    pinmux = <PIN_PD1__GRXCK>,
                         <PIN_PD5__GRX2>,
                         <PIN_PD6__GRX3>,
                         <PIN_PD7__GTX2>,
                         <PIN_PD8__GTX3>,
                         <PIN_PD9__GTXCK>,
                         <PIN_PD10__GTXEN>,
                         <PIN_PD11__GRXDV>,
                         <PIN_PD12__GRXER>,
                         <PIN_PD13__GRX0>,
                         <PIN_PD14__GRX1>,
                         <PIN_PD15__GTX0>,
                         <PIN_PD16__GTX1>,
                         <PIN_PD17__GMDC>,
                         <PIN_PD18__GMDIO>;
                    bias-pull-up;
                };


                pinctrl_macb0_phy_irq: macb0_phy_irq{
                    pinmux = <PIN_PB2__GPIO>;
                    bias-pull-up;
                };
    
            

                pinctrl_macb0_rst: macb0_rst{
                    pinmux = <PIN_PC6__GPIO>;
                    bias-pull-up;
                };

i can see my device and my ip but i can not ping from other device .
i set phy-mode= rmii but i see that my phy-mode mii
dmesg | grep -i phy
booting linux on pyhsical cpu 0x0
libphy fixed mdio bus:probed
libphy:macb_mii_bus:probed
kszphy_probe
kszphy_config_init
micrel ksz8081 f8008000.ethernet-ffffffffff:00: attached phy driver micrel ksz8081 mii_bus:phy_addr=f8008000.ethernet-ffffffff:00, irq=82

what can i do other ?
